# Finding punctuation marks in text with string-methods

Tags: javascript, regex, string

how can I find out when a punctuation(?!;.) or "<" character comes in the string. I don’t want to use an array or compare any letter, but try to solve it with string methods. Something like that:

```
var text = corpus.substr(0, corpus.indexOf(".");
```

Ok, if I explicitly specify a character like a punct, it works fine. The problem with my parsing is that with a long text in a loop, I no longer know how a sentence ends, whether with question marks or exclamation points. I tried following, but it doesn’t work:

```
var text = corpus.substr(0, corpus.indexOf(corpus.search("."));
```

I want to loop through a long string and use every punctuation found to use it as the end-of-sentence character.

Do you know how can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with RegExp and weight it against going character by character and compare ascii codes essentially. Split is another way ( just posted above ).

RegExp solution

```
function getTextUpToPunc( text ) {
    const regExp = /^.+(\!|\?|\.)/mg;
    for (let match; (match = regExp.exec( text )) !== null;) { 
          console.log(match);
    }
}
getTextUpToPunc(
    "what a chunky funky monkey! this is really someting else"
)
```

The key advantage here is that you do not need to loop through the entire string and hold control over the iteration by doing `regExp.exec( text )`.

The `split` solution posted earlier would work but split will loop over the entire string. Typically that would not be an issue but if your strings are thousands upon thousands of characters and you do this operation a lot that it would make sense to think about performance.

And if this function will be ran many many times, a small performance improvement would be to memoize the RegExp creation:

```
    const regExp = /^.+(\!|\?|\.)/mg;
```

Into something like this

```
function getTextUpToPunc( text ) {
    if( !this._regExp ) this._regExp = /^.+(\!|\?|\.)/mg;;

    const regExp = this._regExp;
    for (let match; (match = regExp.exec( text )) !== null;) { 
          console.log(match);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the function works very well. I get my desired result. :-) Unfortunatelly I can't rate you, because I am new here and I dont have enough points to rate somone.

Comment: no problem, thank you for the solution mark, hope this works for you, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression:

```
var text = corpus.split(/[(?!;.)<]/g);
```